# I need to find a particular cell based on 3 factors: Age, $ amount

Tags: excel, formula

I need to be able to enter age and coverage amount and I want it to be able to go to that corresponding cell and tell me the price for that product.

The pricing sheet will have Age on the Y axis and Coverage on the X Axis. Example: I have a 50 year old that wants 20,000 in coverage. I would go down the Y axis and find 50 and then over on the x axis to 20,000.

I want it to tell me what amount is at that particular cell. If I was not clear enough on what I mean let me know and I will try and further explain.

I do not have any code as of yet because I'm not really sure where to start. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you X axis is in sorted order (which seems likely given the values are increasing in coverage) then use the MATCH function for that axis.  For the Y axis, likely the same scenario on age.  The question then becomes whether you want exact matching or nearest ceiling/floor.

```
INDEX( <FULL TABLE RANGE like $A$1:$ABC1000>, MATCH( $agesource, <Full axis like $A$1:$A1000>), MATCH( $coverage, <full axis like $A$1:$ABC1> ) )
```

Comment: I figured it out with your formula. Thanks for the help.